# Network printer does not load webinterface for some clients

Tags: networking, router, printer

At the moment I have a setup that looks like this in the router.

**Network details**

```
Lan IP address 10.10.0.1

Subnet Mask 255.255.248.0

DHCP start IP 10.10.0.2

DHCP end IP 10.10.7.254
```

Now I have several printers \ services on the network and they all can connect to each other and communicate.

The issue I have is that at the moment I have added a new printer to the network, a konica minolta and I set its IP something like **10.10.0.22**

Now all the devices having the same address work

For example, **10.10.0.35** can connect to it easily
All other like **10.10.3.27** can ping and print to it

But only those in the range **10.10.0.254** can connect to the web interface of it.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: IT could be that the printer has been individually assigned a network mask 255.255.255.0 and an IP of 10.10.0.X then only devices under 10.10.0 would be able to access.

Comment: I tought the same thing but unfortunelly i set the IP manually on it with the right mask

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for those wandering Konica minolta has an option to filter IP's . After disabling it from the printer everything working as expected.

Comment: Nice one, yes the next assumption was some sort of firewall on the device.