# Printer not comunicating

Tags: networking, router, printer

I might say its another subent but its a bit more simpler than that, I have a router with few switches connected to it.

Its current configuration is the following:

Lan IP address 10.10.0.1
Subnet Mask 255.255.248.0
DHCP start IP 10.10.0.2
DHCP end IP 10.10.7.254

Now the DHCP server gives out random IPs in that range, for example

10.10.0.29
10.10.3.48
10.10.6.55 etc

I have configured with static IPs in the router the dhcp server to give certain IPs to my devices.

At the moment i have several devices all under 10.10.0.XX

All the computers connected to it can access them.

For example my 10.10.6.20 laptop can access the printer at 10.10.0.17

Today i have added another printer to the network, i can ping it and can connect and communicate with it from devices under 10.10.0.XX . But unlike the rest for example 10.10.6.20 cannot access it but can ping it (  or another type of comunication, only ping works ).

So i'm wondering why unlike the other devices this is not working?

Comment: This appears to be directly related to https://superuser.com/questions/1659741/network-printer-does-not-load-webinterface-for-some-clients & do you really need 2,000 addresses?

Comment: I do need more than 300 so at the begining i have set a range large enough to not be bothered in the future, even if i go lower to get fewer IPs i would still run into the same issue as the max you can get in 1 is 254

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for those wandering Konica minolta has an option to filter IP's . After disabling it from the printer everything working as expected.